# How can I develop two gems together with Bundler?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am developing two gems, let's call them foo and bar. Also foo has a runtime dependency on bar. I am developing both these gems with bundler.

How can I specify bar as a dependency of foo and have bundler resolve that dependency to a local path, without polluting my Gemfile? At the moment the only way I can see to do this is to put `gem "bar", path: "path/to/bar"` in foo's Gemfile, and remove it once bar is on rubygems, but this solution is obviously unsatisfactory as it will break on anybody else's machine until that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear if the dependency is `runtime` or `compile time`.

Have you tried installing `bar` using the local `.gem` file? Once installed in `GEM_HOME`, your `foo` gem should detect it

```
cd /path/to/bar
rake install
```

then

```
cd /path/to/foo
rake build
```

Comment: I did `rake install` on bar and then `bundle install` on foo and it worked perfectly. The `rake build` wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the dependency as a git branch, and then map it to a local path using the instructions here: http://ryanbigg.com/2013/08/bundler-local-paths/

Comment: I really don't want to pollute my Gemfile with references to specific git repos. Also, I should have clarified that I would ideally like people to be able to run the tests without a dependency on Bundler. Eternal-Learner's method means I can simply put my dependencies in the gemspec.

Comment: Cool. That's a good solution, but I think it has the drawback that you will need to keep reinstalling gem bar every time you change it if you want gem foo to see the changes.